# jQuery plugin not working in angular6

Tags: jquery, angular

ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__(...).easeScroll is not a function
    at easeScrollFunc (header.component.ts:372)
    at HeaderComponent.push../src/app/header/header.component.ts.HeaderComponent.ngOnInit (header.component.ts:572)

My componenet calls below jquery method and getting the above mentioned error
    **$("html").easeScroll();**

I added the jquery in my componenet

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Also included the relevent jquery file in angular.json file under scripts 
like below mentioned.

```
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
"src/assets/easeScroll/jquery.easeScroll.js"
```

easeScroll method is part of the jquery.easeScroll JS file

I am not able to find the missing area. Please help me on this and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

Comment: rather than including easeScrolljs file, install it through npm.

Comment: I cant do that , l am converting exsisting jQuery functionality to angular 6 and I am new to it . I am not sure npm easeScroll package is same as we are using

Comment: you can try that once. I think that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used it this way.

Step 1: npm install `jquery`

Step 2: In your component

```
import $ from 'jquery'
declare var $: $
```

Step 3:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        $('.btn-class').click({
            console.log("event clicked")
          })
    }
```

Comment: Jquery functions are works fine for me. But I adding one more plugin easeScroll which is not working and throwing the error